# `easytable` package seems to conflict with `l3doc` class

Tags: tables, dtx, l3doc

I tried to use the `TAB` environment in a .dtx file with `l3doc` class, but It seems to make latex compilation fail.

### MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{easytable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm){|c|c:c:c|}{|c|c:c|}
        a & b & c & d \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8
    \end{TAB}
\end{document}
```

the error also occurs using `ltxdoc`, but not with `article` class for instance:

```
Package `easy' Warning: unrecognized command macro:->\relax \ifmmode \hbox \els
e \leavevmode \null \fi \bgroup \let \do \do@noligs \verbatim@nolig@list \ttfam
ily \verb@eol@error \let \do \@makeother \dospecials \@ifstar {\@sverb }{\@vobe
yspaces \frenchspacing \@sverb } on line 6.

! Use of \@easy@xdef doesn't match its definition.
<argument> g__hook_env/\@easy@xdef /
                         end_code_prop
l.6     \begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm){|c|c:c:c|}{|c|c:c|}
```

Is there a way to fix this?
Or maybe I should abandon `easytable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `|` is used by `l3doc` as a shortcut for verbatim, and `easytable` doesn't like that. You'll have to disable the shortcut here:

```latex
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{easytable}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\|=12 %
    \begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm){|c|c:c:c|}{|c|c:c|}
        a & b & c & d \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8
    \end{TAB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would this obey groups? i.e., if I want this to have a local effect and for that I use `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`; will it work?

Comment: @niranjan yes standard gripping rules apply

Comment: thanks, it solves this error, now I discovered another one hidden behind, have to investigate :-)